# How can I apply the cluster $in with the where in an array type property using strapi V4

Tags: javascript, strapi

My intention is to be able to apply the **$in** cluster to the categories property, but it is an array type property. I know that my implementation is not correct, that's why I want some solution to my case.

I will appreciate any solution.

### Query Example

```js
where: {
   $and: [
     categories: {
       name: {
         $in:["fire"],
       },
     },
   ]
},
```

```js
const entries = await strapi.db
  .query("api::data.data")
  .findMany({
    populate: ["*"],
    orderBy: "id",
    where: {} // todo
});
```

### Entry Example

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "description: "....",
  "categories": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "fire"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "water"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several tests my implementation was functional for an array type property.

```js
where: {
   $and: [
     categories: {
       name: {
         $in:["fire"],
       },
     },
   ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with following code?

```
const entries = await strapi.db
  .query("api::data.data")
  .findMany({
    populate: ["*"],
    orderBy: "id",
    where: {
       $and: [
        categories: {
          name: {
            $in:["fire"],
          },
        },
       ]
    },
});
```

Comment: My implementation was correct, sorry for the inconvenience. Still, I was checking your code and it didn't work because it can't be passed as a string 'categories.name' has to be in format object {categories: {name: }}